# SELECT rows WHERE next n rows satisfy CONDITIONS

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

Let's say we have this resource availability table:

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| date      | obvious, the date                                         |
| timeslot  | we have 12 fixed 2-hour timeslots so this will be 1 to 12 |
| r1        | number of resource type 1 available during this timeslot  |
| r2        | same, for resource type 2                                 |
| r3        | same, for resource type 3                                 |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, I want to see all the available timeslots I can use to do `job #43`. For this job I need 2 units of *r1*, one unit of *r2*, and three units of *r3*. Assuming the job will need one *timeslot* I can use this query:

```
SELECT `date`, `timeslot` FROM `resource_availability` 
WHERE
  `r1` > '1' AND
  `r2` > '0' AND
  `r3` > '2'
ORDER BY 'date`, `timeslot`;
```

However, if I have another job, `job #86` which takes 3 timeslots to complete and could not be stopped-restarted, then is it possible to get safe start times with a query?

I am currently checking continuity in my `while` loop, but thought it might be possible to have the query do that.

If that is possible, I would like to know which is quicker and more efficient. For efficacy evaluation, it should be noted that this table, being a sort of bitmap gets updated quite frequently - i.e. with each job being scheduled the resource availability columns get updated.

Also, it is fairly obvious the purpose of this system is to allow examining *what-ifs*. If my approach is not optimal, what better alternatives there are?

Should the last question be *one too many*, please ignore it, or let me know in the comments and I'd delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Whew... I put together an idea that may get you what you want. Forgive me if it takes a bit to understand, but I hope you see that it's actually a fairly straightforward solution to a moderately complex problem.

I would build the query (in PHP) to have n self-joins where n is the number of time slots needed for the job. The self-joins join the *next* consecutive timeslot, and the results are thinned based on resources being available in all the slots. Note that you could move the dynamically-created WHERE clauses into the JOIN conditions... I *have* seen versions of MySQL which will improve speed that way.

## php code:

```
// $r1, $r3, and $r3 are the required resources for this job.

$join_format = 'JOIN timeslots AS %s ON %date = %s.date AND %s.timeslot+1 = %s.timeslot';
$where_format = '(%s.r1 >= '.$r1.' AND %s.r2 >= '.$r2.' AND %s.r3 >= '.$r3.')';

$joins = array();
$wheres = array("block1.date > CURDATE()",
                sprintf($where_format, "block1", "block1", "block1")
                );
$select_list = 'block1.date, block1.timeslot as starting_time, block' . $slots_needed . '.timeslot as ending_time';

for($block = 2; $block <= $slots_needed; $block++) {
  $join_alias = "block" . $block;
  $previous_alias = "block" . ($block-1);
  $joins[] = sprintf($join_format, $join_alias, $previous_alias,$join_alias, $previous_alias, $join_alias);
  $wheres[] = sprintf($where_format, $join_alias, $join_alias, $join_alias);
}

$query_format = 'SELECT %s FROM timeslots as block1 %s WHERE %s GROUP BY block1.date, block1.timeslot ORDER BY block1.date ASC, block1.timeslot ASC';
$joins_string = implode(' ', $joins);
$wheres_string = implode(' AND ', $wheres);
$query = sprintf($query_format, $select_list, $joins_string, $wheres_string);
```

To the best of my intention, that should yield a query like this (for 2 needed blocks with 1 each of the resources needed:

## resultant SQL:

```
SELECT 
  block1.date,
  block1.timeslot as starting_time, 
  block2.timeslot as ending_time
FROM 
  timeslots AS block1
  JOIN timeslots AS block2
    ON block1.date = block2.date AND block1.timeslot+1 = block2.timeslot
WHERE
  block1.date > CURDATE()
  AND (block1.r1 >= 1 AND block1.r2 >= 1 AND block1.r3 >= 1)
  AND (block2.r1 >= 1 AND block2.r2 >= 1 AND block2.r3 >= 1)
GROUP BY
  block1.date, block1.timeslot
ORDER BY
  block1.date ASC, block1.timeslot ASC
```

and it should yield results such as:

## expected result set:

```
+------------+---------------+-------------+
|    date    | starting_time | ending_time |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
| 2001-01-01 |       1       |      2      |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
| 2001-01-01 |       2       |      3      |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
| 2001-01-01 |       7       |      8      |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
| 2001-01-01 |       8       |      9      |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
| 2001-01-02 |       4       |      5      |
+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Notice that if there are 2 blocks needed, but 3 available (consecutively), the query *will* return both options (the first and second OR the second and third available times).

Comment: +1 Thank you. Quite impressive -- both your knowledge of SQL, and the amount of effort you have put into this answer. But, as I said in my question, currently, I can get what I want, with PHP. I was mainly looking for ways to improve performance, or have a simpler solution. As I see it, apparently none will be had with pure SQL as the hybrid solution is both simpler and less resource-consuming. I will wait to see if others would post answers with alternative methods -- but just for curiosity, as I have come to believe nothing would beat my current solution.

Comment: This answer moves the php work to the "front" to build the query; as opposed to what I think you implied you are doing presently, where you are iterating over the slots when the query returns. There is an order of magnitude less work done in PHP in my solution. It iterates n times if there are n required slots. Doing the evaluation of continuity after the query requires approx. n*x, where x is the number of hours in the database with the appropriate resources. I thank you for the +1, but I also hope you play with this solution to see how it fits; I am confident it is a drastic improvement.

Comment: I guess the point is not which PHP script takes a shorter time; it is `PHP` vs. `SQL JOIN`. Please note that the table could have `4380` records (one year's worth of data), or even more. I have a vague idea about how `JOIN`s are implemented, but we have `2` comparisons per `JOIN` and `n-1 JOINS` for `n timeslot`. So for `4 timeslots`, we have `6` comparisons per record or (4380 - 1) * 6 = `26274` comparisons. Of course I could be wrong about the number of comparisons each `JOIN` would need per total records, or perhaps, the `JION`s are only attempted on filtered records (by `WHERE`).

Comment: Yes, the JOINs are highly optimized by MySQL. And the first time it finds ANY mismatch in any of the match criteria, the entire row is junked from the results and the query moves on. So, for instance, if the first-join'd timeslot does not have the required resources, the work of the second join never happens. It's very efficient when written like this, and the "full" amount of work for these comparisons is only performed for complete matches (where there are n contiguous blocks with good resources). All "rejected" timeslots represent a performance win compared to doing it in PHP.

Comment: Further, you can (should) add a either a LIMIT clause to this query, returning perhaps just the next 12 available slots, or another WHERE clause for bounding the future `WHERE block1.date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE, INTERVAL 14 day)`. These techniques will yield almost blazing-fast results. There will only be 14*12 rows evaluated for block1, then only the rows which match the resource criteria are JOIN'd to block2, then only the rows in block2 which match the resources cause a join to block3, etc. It's one of my favorite features of how MySQL does JOINs: it will stop working on them as soon as it can.